# Display top 1 columns in column group in ssrs

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I had created one report in SSRS. Its shows as below.

```
        Product1        Product2        Product3        Product4
AEQ     1000            1000            1000            1000
IEQ     2000            2000            2000            2000
Prop    3000            3000            3000            3000
```

I want to show only top column in this group.

```
        Product1
AEQ     1000
IEQ     2000
Prop    3000
```

Is there any way to display like this in RDLC reporting?

Answer (score 0):

```
=iif(RunningValue(Fields!strperiod.Value, CountDistinct, "PaymentReceived") = 1, False, True)
```